# Prevent movement of user interface when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, mobile-safari

I'm working on a little app which uses Sencha Touch 2 for the user interface. Right now I'm running it in Safari on my iPad and iPhone.

My problem is that whenever I tap a text field, Safari brings up the virtual keyboard and pushes the whole web view upwards, off the screen.

This doesn't look very natural, since the top-toolbar is not visible anymore.

Here are two screenshots which demonstrate the problem.
In the second screenshot you can see the effect when the keyboard is visible.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior, and have Safari *resize* the user interface instead?

> [image: Normal view]

---

> [image: Keyboard enabled]

Comment: Did you get a fix to this?

Comment: @AdilMalik: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Any update about this silly issue ???? any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Apple wants this behavior, but [someone](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?170450-Toolbar-gets-pushed-off-screen-when-virtual-opens) suggested a little hack using window.scrollTo():

```
listeners: {
    focus: function() {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It's still not perfect, as the user can see the initial movement which gets fixed right afterwards. Besides that it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this code in launch function in app.js worked for me:

```
 if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
        Ext.Viewport.on('painted', function () {
            Ext.Viewport.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        });
    }

    if (Ext.os.is.iOS) {

        Ext.Viewport.on('painted', function () {
            Ext.Viewport.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for me.
You move the topbar into the container.

```
xtype: 'container',
                docked: 'top',
                height: '100%',
                html: '',
                itemId: 'MyContainer',
                width: '100%',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        itemId: 'topBar',
                        title: 'Obec Webchat',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'hbox',
                            align: 'start'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                action: 'back',
                                id: 'BackButton',
                                itemId: 'BackButton',
                                margin: '5 70% 5 15',
                                ui: 'back',
                                text: 'Home'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        docked: 'bottom',
                        height: '95%',
                        html: '<iframe src="http://webim.obec.local/" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>',
                        itemId: 'MyContainer1',
                        width: '100%'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to call the `blur()` method on `textfield`

```
// Assuming the id of textfield - "textFieldId"
Ext.getCmp('textFieldId').blur();
```

> Attempts to `forcefully` blur input focus for the field.

Comment: Doesn't that hide the keyboard, since the textfield loses its focus? The point is that I actually want the keyboard to be there, but without half of the user interface pushed off the screen.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Half Keyboard + rest half your app ... ?

Comment: See the two screenshots. On the lower screenshot you can see that the keyboard pushed up the whole user interface. The top toolbar is gone. I want to display the keyboard without it pushing the UI out on the top of the screen. Instead it should resize.

Answer (score -2):

If you this using html into Sencha elements must remove something tag html. Or can you put tag 
 in the source html code. I hope help you. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you write something code? and I say where is the mistake. Thanks